# How can I get battery usage history on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, battery

Windows 8 has a feature to get battery usage history with

```
powercfg /batteryreport
```

However, there's no such option for `powercfg` on Windows 7. How can I get battery usage history on Windows 7?

I want to make sure that the new battery I bought today has not been used before.

Comment: Powercfg is also available in Windows 7. Go cmd and run as administrator. Type command powercfg /a .. see what is output of this command

Comment: @TechieGossip It is available but lacks `/batteryreport` option. I tried `powercfg /?` (in non-admin mode) and it returned all posible options but `/batteryreport`.